# I'm gatting "Set the RESUME variable to override this." Error when i try to sudo apt upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

**I don't know why this error coming. and this one is normal?**

os : 5.8.0-38-generic #43~20.04.1-Ubuntu

**my Terminal Output:**

```
kaushal@kaushal:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-lato gstreamer1.0-vaapi javascript-common libdislocker0.7
  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libjs-jquery libllvm10 libllvm10:i386
  libmbedcrypto3 libruby2.7 rake ruby ruby-minitest ruby-net-telnet
  ruby-power-assert ruby-test-unit ruby-xmlrpc ruby2.7 rubygems-integration
  ubuntu-restricted-addons
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libnetplan0 libnss-systemd libpam-systemd libsystemd0 libsystemd0:i386 libudev1
  libudev1:i386 linux-firmware netplan.io systemd systemd-sysv systemd-timesyncd
  udev
13 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 108 MB of archives.
After this operation, 74.8 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libnss-systemd amd64 245.4-4ubuntu3.4 [95.9 kB]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libudev1 amd64 245.4-4ubuntu3.4 [80.3 kB]
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 libudev1 i386 245.4-4ubuntu3.4 [83.1 kB]
Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 udev amd64 245.4-4ubuntu3.4 [1,365 kB]
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 systemd-timesyncd amd64 245.4-4ubuntu3.4 [28.1 kB]
Get:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 systemd-sysv amd64 245.4-4ubuntu3.4 [10.3 kB]
Get:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libpam-systemd amd64 245.4-4ubuntu3.4 [186 kB]
Get:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 systemd amd64 245.4-4ubuntu3.4 [3,805 kB]
Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 libsystemd0 i386 245.4-4ubuntu3.4 [292 kB]
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libsystemd0 amd64 245.4-4ubuntu3.4 [273 kB]
Get:11 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libnetplan0 amd64 0.101-0ubuntu3~20.04.2 [28.5 kB]
Get:12 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 netplan.io amd64 0.101-0ubuntu3~20.04.2 [94.2 kB]
Get:13 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-firmware all 1.187.8 [102 MB]
Fetched 108 MB in 56s (1,926 kB/s)                                                                                   
(Reading database ... 203312 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnss-systemd_245.4-4ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnss-systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) over (245.4-4ubuntu3.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libudev1_245.4-4ubuntu3.4_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libudev1:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.3) ...
Unpacking libudev1:i386 (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) over (245.4-4ubuntu3.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libudev1_245.4-4ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libudev1:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) over (245.4-4ubuntu3.3) ...
Setting up libudev1:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) ...
Setting up libudev1:i386 (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) ...
(Reading database ... 203312 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-udev_245.4-4ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking udev (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) over (245.4-4ubuntu3.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../1-systemd-timesyncd_245.4-4ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking systemd-timesyncd (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) over (245.4-4ubuntu3.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../2-systemd-sysv_245.4-4ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking systemd-sysv (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) over (245.4-4ubuntu3.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../3-libpam-systemd_245.4-4ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpam-systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) over (245.4-4ubuntu3.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../4-systemd_245.4-4ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) over (245.4-4ubuntu3.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../5-libsystemd0_245.4-4ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libsystemd0:i386 (245.4-4ubuntu3.3) ...
Unpacking libsystemd0:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) over (245.4-4ubuntu3.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../6-libsystemd0_245.4-4ubuntu3.4_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libsystemd0:i386 (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) over (245.4-4ubuntu3.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../7-libnetplan0_0.101-0ubuntu3~20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnetplan0:amd64 (0.101-0ubuntu3~20.04.2) over (0.100-0ubuntu4~20.04.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../8-netplan.io_0.101-0ubuntu3~20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking netplan.io (0.101-0ubuntu3~20.04.2) over (0.100-0ubuntu4~20.04.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../9-linux-firmware_1.187.8_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-firmware (1.187.8) over (1.187.7) ...
Setting up linux-firmware (1.187.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-38-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda1
I: (UUID=b0e7eead-39f6-4e20-a3c9-c40f0823e8e7)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-36-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda1
I: (UUID=b0e7eead-39f6-4e20-a3c9-c40f0823e8e7)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Setting up libnetplan0:amd64 (0.101-0ubuntu3~20.04.2) ...
Setting up libsystemd0:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) ...
Setting up libsystemd0:i386 (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) ...
Setting up udev (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/resolved ...
Setting up netplan.io (0.101-0ubuntu3~20.04.2) ...
Setting up systemd-timesyncd (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) ...
Setting up systemd-sysv (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) ...
Setting up libnss-systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) ...
Setting up libpam-systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.16-2ubuntu2.1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.3) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-38-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda1
I: (UUID=b0e7eead-39f6-4e20-a3c9-c40f0823e8e7)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
kaushal@kaushal:~$
```

Comment: It is not an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a normal information message and not an error.

It informs you that your resume device is `UUID=b0e7eead-39f6-4e20-a3c9-c40f0823e8e7`.

There is nothing to worry about.

Comment: thank you, I just worried. It views some time only so I thought it was told me to resume something.

Comment: It tells you how to change the resume device if you want it.

Comment: ok, I got it. thank you again.

Comment: If that's the case you should post an answer on the dupe noting this.

Comment: I don't think it is a dupe. The other one is about haow to change the RESUME. I didn't VTC.